# Tinymce - Convert image url to html image url

Tags: tinymce

This is question about tinymce... Current image editor is slow for because it demands opening popup for every new picture I want to add. I have my own external image gallery where each image contains it's url so copy-paste of url's is very easy and fast...
I would like to have button similar to Bold that does following:
To editor I paste url of image (for example: www.site.com/image.jpg) and when i select this url and click on my new button it converts image url to <img src='www.site.com/image.jpg'> and shows image in editor.
I searched plugins and found nothing similar to this.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Ilija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!
In documentation there is example how to manipulate text in editor from external commands... end even set them as button

Comment: where? please share with us a link